# Firefox: Any way to allow javascript to disable or replace the context menu only to specific domains?

Tags: firefox, javascript, context-menu, internet-security

This is something that's commonly abused, so I almost always want it to be off, *except* when I'm using a handful of large webapps that use the feature properly, such as Google Docs. I know there's a universal toggle for this in the Firefox preferences; but is there a way to grant this privilege *only* to certain domains? Something like a whitelist?

Comment: I would really like to know this as well!

Comment: I have found a way, through a Greasemonkey script! See here: http://superuser.com/questions/366016/firefox-right-click-easy-support-for-the-firefox-or-the-sites-menu/443734#443734

Answer (score 2):

you can try no-script Addone for firefox and allow the script on the few sites you want.
You also can enable each script file saparate if you want.

http://noscript.net/

EDIT: 
If you only want to block the contextmenu itself you can follow these steps:

edit-> preferences -> content -> advanced options of JScript -> set the toggle to "disable or replace context menu"

Comment: The No-Script Addon will let you enable Javascript on a per-site or per-domain basis, and has it off by default.  When you encounter a site you can enable scripting by clicking on its icon in the statusbar.  It's exactly what you want.

Comment: But Kenny, this is not site-specific. @Ultra: Noscript is site-specific, but it doesn't allow you to allow all Javascript except context-menu changes, which is what we're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

i know this is an old question, but it's exactly the one i've been trying to find an answer for, and the ones here don't seem to fully satisfy the original question.

It appears to me the only way to regulate ***just*** context menu access to specific sites is using Firefox's "hidden" CAPS feature:

https://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/components/ConfigPolicy.html

It can be tricky to manage the policies, and any time you want to add a new site to the list, you have to edit the user.js file & restart Firefox.

i'm not really a fan of using add-ons to manage built-in features, since i want the policies to be persistent & i see no reason to let Firefox suck even more memory for an add-on i'll rarely utilize once my settings are established.

The only question i have about doing this through CAPS is how to address the actual context menu option.

Comment: For those coming to this question in the far future, [CAPS has been completely removed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=913734#c32) from Firefox so this answer no longer applies.